# Ransack Searching Filtered Based on Two Attributes

Tags: search, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I am currently using Ransack and trying to display records from two different Models for searching.

In my case it is Vendors and Users. Both own campaigns.

I have tried to combine the two results into one table using:

```
@search = current_user.campaigns + current_user.vendor.campaigns.where.not(:user_id =>current_user.id).search(params[:q])
```

This will display the table but when I activate the Ransack search part, I get an error

```
no implicit conversion of Ransack::Search into Array
```

Is there a different way for me to be able achieve the desired results using Ransack?

I have also tried:

```
 @search = Campaign.search(:vendor_location_id => current_user.vendor.id) but I need to also make sure the current_users campaigns show up as well, not just the vendors
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

**Solved with this formula:**

```
      @search = Campaign.where('(user_id LIKE ?) OR (vendor_id LIKE ?)',current_user.id, current_user.vendor.id).order(:name).search(params[:q])
```